# how to handle 'index out of range' Swift 4

Tags: arrays, uitableview, indexing

I have an String array like this  `["Compliance,", "Partial-Compliance,", "Non-Compliance,", "Non-Compliance"] . I am getting an "Index Out of range exception" when trying to display these values in table view I think this is because table view contains 8 index path and it has only 4 elements but I want to know is there any solution to handle this "Index out of range" exception so that my app will not crash. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show.Your.Code.

Comment: Thanks vadian for replying....I just asked it for some knowledge that whether we can do this or not and if yes than how??

Comment: Of course you can do that. However on Stackoverflow people are willing to fix the issues of your code or improve your code but are not willing to write the code for you.